# Render HTML for multilevel JSON Tree Structure

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, json

Please help me out to render html for given json.

I need a recursive function which will build tree structure.

Given Json is a two way tree. A node can have multiple trees. But each tree has only two nodes Left and right.

[Required Output Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLO6z.png)

```
{
  "tree_0":{
    "6629037861":{
      "tree_0":{
        "3669554975":{
          "tree_0":{
            "2039960559":false,"1328034918":false
          }
        },
        "3275450540":false
      }
    },
    "7652442898":{
      "tree_0":{
        "5586200617":{
          "tree_0":{
             "3265277560":false,"5222124962":false
          }
        },
        "4878276779":false
      }
    }
 },
 "tree_1":{
   "4521813934":{
     "tree_0":{
       "4437207316":false,
       "4034199320":false
     }
   },
   "8065858910":false
},
"tree_2":{
  "5350611753":false,
  "9257374001":false
},
"tree_3":{
   "8497444831":false,
   "8713068590":false
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand what exactly you mean in "only two nodes Left and right" but i hope this base function will help you to adjust to your needs...

The variable it use in the example "treeObj" is your full json that you posted.

```
     function renderTree(tree) {
        var html = "<ul>";
        if( tree instanceof Object) {
            for(var i in tree) {
                html += "<li>" + i;
                html += renderTree(tree[i]);
                html += "</li>";
            }
        }
        else {
            html += "<li>" + tree + "</li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        return html;
    }

    document.write(renderTree(treeObj));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working. But I need a out like image mentioned in the question description.